# How do I grant admin rights to my ADO project?

Tags: azure-devops, admin

I need to grant admin rights to somebody helping me troubleshoot my project/pipeline.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about "how to ask a good question" and "how to give a reproducible example". This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @user12322341 Does the answer below solve your problem? If so,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).If not,please feel free to ask.

Comment: @user12322341, Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?Could you get the admin rights now? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project setting -> Overview -> Project administrators -> Add administrator

or Project setting -> Permission -> Project Administrators group -> Members -> Add

or Organization setting -> Users -> Manger user -> grant project administrator permission

[image]
[image]